# Randomly getting logged out from admin session (Ubuntu)

Tags: logout, administrator

I recently switched over from Windows to Ubuntu and I've been trying to learn some bash scripting. I came across the ctrl+alt+F2 command and, curious as we humans are, I clicked the combination without any notion as to what was about to happen. When the raw terminal came up I tried to switch back to the graphical interface, quickly realizing that I did not know how to do this. In a half-panic, I taped the power off button and my computer shutdown (note: I did not force the shutdown).

Upon restarting my computer, I realized that I could no longer maintain my session open on my admin account. After about 20 seconds I would get kicked off the session with no warning. I am receiving an error but (new as I am to Ubuntu) I'm not quite sure how to track it down. I am able to maintain a guest session going indefinitely but it is my admin session that gets logged out automatically.

Can anyone provide some assistance please?

EDIT:
After creating a new sudo user, I have ruled that it is the account that is corrupted. I did some further research and found that deleting the .Xauthority file on the home directory of the corrupted used is sometimes the answer as when you log into the account again, the .Xauthority file should be recreated. However, after I deleted the .Xauthority file, it would no longer get recreated and I could no longer log into the account. Any ideas?

On a separate note, this is only a GUI problem, as I can log into the account perfectly through the raw terminal (ctrl+alt+F2) and maintain that session indefinitely.

EDIT2:
Ended up cloning the profile by moving all my files into a new account and giving it sudo privileges. After some research it seems as if I corrupted the .Xauthority or .profile files under my home directory when I shutdown after launching the raw terminal from inside my corrupted profile. I will try tinkering with this some more but as of now the issue is **SOLVED**

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but Ctrl+Alt+F7 will switch you back to your graphical session you hit Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6.

Answer (score 0):

**Part one:**

- Start `recovery mode`
- Select `drop to root shell`
- Type `mount -o rw,remount /`
- Type `adduser username sudo` #username=your user name
- Type `shutdown -r now`

**Part two:**

- Repeat first three steps of **Part one**
- Type `passwd username`

**That's it.**

Comment: This didnt work, after the mount command nothing seemed to happen. When I followed up with the adduser command and tried adding my admin user back, it said that the user already existed. I tried proceeding with the listed steps but the issue remains. Any ideas?

Comment: Try the same with different username you haven't made yet.